# combinatorial formula for Hermite polynomials

Tags: combinatorics, hermite-polynomials

From [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermite_polynomials#Explicit_expression), the Hermite polynomial has a combinatorial description as 
$$
H_r (x)= r!\sum^{[r/2]}_{s=0}\frac{(-1)^s}{s! (r-2s)!}(2x)^{r-2s}
$$
I am trying to express the following equation in terms of the Hermite polynomials 
$$
f_r (x)= r!\sum^{[r/2]}_{s=0}\frac{(v)^s}{s! (r-2s)!}(x)^{r-2s}
$$
but am unable to figure out how to do this, as it is slightly different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From
$$
H_r (x)= r!\sum^{[r/2]}_{s=0}\frac{(-1)^s}{s! (r-2s)!}(2x)^{r-2s}
$$
we have
\begin{align*}
H_r (ix/(2\sqrt{v})) &= r!\sum^{[r/2]}_{s=0}\frac{(-1)^s}{s! (r-2s)!}(ix/\sqrt{v})^{r-2s}\\
 & = r!\sum^{[r/2]}_{s=0}\frac{(-1)^s (\sqrt{v}/i)^{2s - r}  }{s! (r-2s)!}x^{r-2s}\\
 & = r!\sum^{[r/2]}_{s=0}\frac{(-1)^s (-i\sqrt{v})^{2s - r}  }{s! (r-2s)!}x^{r-2s}\\
 & = r!\sum^{[r/2]}_{s=0}\frac{(-1)^s (-i)^{2s} \sqrt{v}^{2s}(-i\sqrt{v})^{-r}  }{s! (r-2s)!}x^{r-2s}\\
 & = r!\sum^{[r/2]}_{s=0}\frac{v^{s}(-i\sqrt{v})^{-r}  }{s! (r-2s)!}x^{r-2s}\\
&= (-i\sqrt{v})^{-r} f_r(x)
\end{align*}
if I haven't made any mistakes.